# Is this theorem equivalent to "existential instantiation" rule?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

In Enderton's, There is a theorem called "existential instantiation", it says:

> Assume that the constant symbol $c$ does not occur in $\alpha ,\beta , \Gamma$ and that:
>   $$ \Gamma\cup\{\alpha^x_c\}\vdash\beta$$
>   Then
>   $$\Gamma\cup\{\exists\alpha\}\vdash\beta$$

I've googled the name of the theorem but found that on Wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_instantiation) for example, It says something else namely, Given $\exists x\alpha$ we can infer $\alpha^x_c$ for some contant symbol $c$ that has not been used before in the deduction. 
It seems that what wikipedia states is the converse of the EL theorems in Enderton's and I don't see how both forms coincede.

Could anyone clarify for me how they state the same fact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the *existential elimination* rule of *Natural Deduction* :

> from $\Gamma, \varphi(y/x) \vdash \psi$, infer $\Gamma, \exists x \varphi \vdash \psi$, provided that $y$ is not free in $\psi$, or in any assumption in $\Gamma$.

The other rule of *Natural Deduction* for $\exists$ is the *existential introduction* rule :

> from $\varphi(t)$, infer $\exists x \varphi(x)$

which in Enderton's system correspons to : $\vdash \alpha^x_t \rightarrow \exists \alpha$, that can be easily derived from Ax.2 : $\forall x \alpha \rightarrow \alpha^x_t$.

---

In order to understand Enderton's (apparent) "idiosyncratic" approach, we can see the very simple proof of **Coroll.24H (Rule EI)**, page 124 :

> Assume that the constant symbol $c$ does not occur in $\varphi, \psi$ or $\Gamma$, and that $\Gamma, \varphi^x_c \vdash \psi$.

By contraposition we have $\Gamma, \lnot \psi \vdash \lnot \varphi^x_c$ and by [previous result] we obtain : $\Gamma, \lnot \psi \vdash \forall \lnot \varphi^x_c$.

Applying contraposition again, we have the desired result.

"Informally", we can rephrase Enderton's proof as follows :

- Assume $\Gamma$ and $\exists x \varphi$;
- by [Existential instantiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_instantiation) we have :

> $\exists x \varphi \vdash \varphi^x_c$, where $c$ is an arbitrary *constant* symbol which does not occur in $\varphi, \psi$ or $\Gamma$.

By hypotheses :

- $\Gamma, \varphi^x_c \vdash \psi$;

thus, we can conclude with :

> > $\Gamma, \exists x \varphi \vdash \psi$.

Why not ? The issue is that the rule :

> from $\exists x \varphi$, infer $\varphi^x_c$, for a new constant $c$

is not part of Enderton's **Deductive Calculus** [see page 109-on].

Why so ? Because, without some "tricky" provisos this rule is not sound in Enderton's calculus.

Assume that we can add this rule to the system; then we can "manufacture" this simple derivation :

1) $\exists x \varphi(x)$ --- assumed

2) $\varphi^x_c$ --- from 1), with a new constant $c$ not occurring in it.

Thus, we have the derivation : $\exists x \varphi(x) \vdash \varphi^x_c$.

Then we apply to it :

> **Coroll.24G** [page 124] : Assume that $\Gamma \vdash \varphi^x_c$, where the constant symbol $c$ does not occur in $\Gamma$ or in $\varphi$. Then $\Gamma \vdash \forall x \varphi$, and there is a deduction of $\forall x \varphi$ from $\Gamma$ in which $c$ does not occur

with $\Gamma = \{ \exists x \varphi(x) \}$, and we have a new derivation :

> $\exists x \varphi(x) \vdash \forall x \varphi$.

Finally apply the **Deduction Th** to get :

> > $\vdash \exists x \varphi(x) \rightarrow \forall x \varphi$.

But this formula is clearly *invalid*; consider its arithmetical instance : $\exists x(x \ne 0) \rightarrow \forall x(x \ne 0)$.

Comment: Where is the elimination of the quantifier  in the existential elimination rule? Also, In enderton's: $x$ must not occur in neither $\phi,\psi$ nor in any formula in $\Gamma$ but you require different condition. Another thing: it seems that the rule wiki talks about is existential introduction not elemination.

Comment: @MathsLover - What Wiki call *Existential instantiation* is $\exists$-elimination; $\exists$-introduction corresponds to [Existential generalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_generalization).

Comment: Ok but you didn't get me, I wonder: If both the rule of quantifier elimination in natural deduction (**As stated in  wikipedia**) and quantifier instantiation in Enderton's, capture the same intuitive idea, I don't see how both do capture the "same" idea. The statement stated in wiki seems more intuitive for me than the theorem in Enderton's so my essential question: How do we know that both are the same? notice that formulation of both statements are apparently different

Comment: By "both formulations", I mean this formulation :http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_instantiation , and the one given in Enderton's as stated in the question.

Comment: @MathsLover- as you can see in [Rules of inference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rules_of_inference) : **Existential Instantiation** (or **Existential Elimination**), there are different way of formalizing the rules for $\exists$.

Answer (score 0):

If you can infer $A$ from $B$, and you have $\Gamma \cup \{A\} \vdash \beta$, then you can conclude that $\Gamma \cup \{B\} \vdash \beta$. (The left-side of a turnstile is like the left-hand side of an implication: strengthening an assumption preserves validity.) Hence there is no conflict between Enderton's rule that operates on an assumption and the rule you found in the Wikipedia that operates on a conclusion.